# Doesn't refresh a list of a page when I change with the side menu Ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

[GIF that describes my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbGqk.gif)

hello everyone!

I'm new to ionic 4 as well as angular

when I change the page with the sidemenu and return to the initial page, the information in my list does not load as seen in the [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbGqk.gif)
I print on the console when ngOnDestroy is used since I think it has something to do with it
My project is based on this [code](https://github.com/bezael/crud-ionic4)

This is my code

HTML of SideMenu

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
    <ion-menu contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Menú</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">
            <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" routerLink="{{p.url}}">
              <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>
                {{p.title}}
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

TS of SideMenu

```
public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Modelos',
      url: '/home',
      icon: 'home'
    }
  ];

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
```

HTML of my page

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      Llaveros
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let keyChain of keyChains | filter:findText">
      <ion-item lines="inset" button [routerLink]="['/details-key-chain', keyChain.id]">
        <ion-label>

        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

TS of my page

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  keyChains: KeyChainI[];

  constructor(
    private keyChainService: KeyChainService,
    public popoverController: PopoverController,
    public alertController: AlertController
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ngOnInit");
    this.keyChainService.getKeyChains().subscribe(res => this.keyChains = res);
  }
}
```

my service of firebase

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { KeyChainI } from '../models/chain-key.interface';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class KeyChainService {
  private keyChainCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<KeyChainI>;
  keyChains: Observable<KeyChainI[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.keyChainCollection = db.collection<KeyChainI>('keyChains');
    this.keyChains = this.keyChainCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(
      actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      }
    ));
  }

  getKeyChains() {
    return this.keyChains;
  }

}
```

I'm sorry if I'm a fool, but I'm new to this world, please help me

Comment: Kindly post only minimal code.

Comment: sorry, there was certainly a lot of code, I already updated only with the necessary code

Comment: can you try removing filter:findText

Comment: it doesn't work, I think the problem is when onDestroy is running, after that, it doesn't load anything

Answer (score 2):

Can you please change your `Home component.ts` as below and check once

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  keyChains: KeyChainI[];

  constructor(
    private keyChainService: KeyChainService,
    public popoverController: PopoverController,
    public alertController: AlertController
  ) { 
    this.keyChainService.getKeyChains().subscribe(res => this.keyChains = res);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ngOnInit");
  }
  ionViewWillEnter(){
       this.keyChainService.getKeyChains().subscribe(res => this.keyChains = res);
  }
}
```

Comment: `ngOnInit` call once when your component gets initialized and the constructor will get called every time.
You can choose the ionic lifecycle hook methods that will run each time when yoour component will get called

Comment: Instead of call it on constructor it's better to do it with ionViewWillEnter(), as above.

Comment: I tried both and it doesn't work, I used console.log to see what methods were called when changing pages with the side menu and the constructor, ngOnInit and ionViewWillEnter.

Comment: I forgot to comment something, when I add an object, the information appears again, as seen in this [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi5aM.gif)
Thanks for trying to help me